# How can I add the different blocks in footer for each store in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

Hello I am new in magento.I want to add the different blocks in footer for each store.
Like I Have created a CMS block for adding the telephone number in footer and add this block in local.xml and telephone number cms block is showing in footer 
but my problem is that I have multiple store and want to add the different telephone number according to store.

How can I do that .Is there any way to use the different block for different store in footer from admin section.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating static block to display the telephone number,

you can get store telephone number form the system configuration(Admin panel).

> System > Configuration > General > Store Information

[image]

In this you can give telephone number for each store

And you can get the Telephone number by the following code

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');
```

**Get the Value in the CMS page**

```
{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.I just gave the example to add the telephone block but I need to add the different block for different stores like contact us block will be different for each store

Answer (score 1):

You can amend the Gerard answer as:

Edit your footer and add the following code:

```
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
    OR
    $store  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

whichever you feel better and then use:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_'.$store)->toHtml(); ?>
```

Now create static blocks for each store. just use the identifier for them as `footer_1`,`footer_2`, `footer_3` where `1,2,3` are the `store ids`. And if you prefer to use store code then use `footer_storecode1`, `footer_store2`, `footer_store3`.

In this way you don't have to edit the code each time, but note that you have to create blocks for each store then.

Answer (score 0):

Check your footer template file where the custom block is added. It should look like:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_contact_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Change this to:

```
<?php 
    $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
    if ($storeCode == 'store1') {
        $footer_contact_id = 'footer_contact_store1';
    }
    elseif ($storeCode == 'store2') {
        $footer_contact_id = 'footer_contact_store2';
    }

    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($footer_contact_id)->toHtml();
?>
```

You can check the store codes in backend: `system -> manage stores`.

Comment: If I create a   one New store  and two stores already created then I need to change again in code for adding block for third store.Is there any way that I can set the blocks in footer from admin on basis of particular store.

Comment: You can't set cms blocks depending on store view in Magento backend. You'll have to do this programmatically.

Comment: Use a template file (instead of static block) that retrieves contact information based on store view.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your template code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_contact_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

1. Go to cms/static blocks and create a block with the id footer_contact_id. 
   Set storeview to your FIRST store and enter the information.

2.Copy the block with the same id
Set the storeview to your SECOND store. and change some of the information.

3.Now check the stores :)